# Generate administrative divisions from GPS coordinates?

Tags: gps, gis

I have a fairly large set of geographic coordinates in decimal degrees that I hope to generate the administrative (political) divisions for. I am looking for something open source that could run from the Linux command terminal and do something like the following:

INPUT:
43.052222
-87.956111

OUTPUT:
0. United States
1. Wisconsin
2. Milwaukee
3. Milwaukee

I am currently looking into Nominatim/osm2pgsql and GDAL but am unsure if they can do what I am looking for, so if anyone has any suggestions I would be very grateful. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

After some further searching, [RubyGeocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/) looks like it's going to do the trick. Here is the output for reference:

```
$ geocode -s geocoder_ca "43.052222, -87.956111"
Latitude:         43.052223
Longitude:        -87.956106
Full address:     1630 34th ST N, Milwaukee, WI 53207, United States
City:             Milwaukee
State/province:   WI
Postal code:      53207
Country:          United States
Google map:       http://maps.google.com/maps?q=43.052223,-87.956106
```

There is no county but beggars can't be choosy!